# Creating a custom block without using the Drupal 7 block hooks

Tags: drupal

Just wanted to know if it's possible to create a custom block in Drupal 7 without using the block hooks hook_block_info() or hook_block_configure() etc.

My requirement is adding dynamic blocks to the Drupal system.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: It could be a panel inside a static block as well. or old-school iframes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by creating 'dynamic' blocks, but two ways to create blocks without writing a module are

1. Going to admin/structure/block and clicking on 'Add block' and creating one by hand there... you could even have a block that contains php code if you enable the 'Php filter' module on your site.
2. You could create a block view.  Go to admin/structure/views/add and add a view with a block display.  Not sure if you're familiar with the [Views module](http://drupal.org/project/views/), but that's another way folks create blocks that are lists of node content, but could also just contain text, etc.

Does that answer your question?

=================== EDIT ======================

If you're trying to do this programmatically, take a look at how the block module does it!
In Drupal 7, that would be the **block_add_block_form_submit()** function in modules/block/block.admin.inc.  That's the function that processes the form when you create a block via the admin form in #1 above.  You can use that code to create as many blocks as you want.  Notice that it just places all the info necessary into the DB without calling any additional functions.

Comment: I am trying to create a block programmatically when i wish, calling a function like that of the block_hook ones based on parameters like block title, description etc. The block should only be created when i call those function(s) and not like the block_hook.

Does this clear things up?

Comment: Ah ok.  Now I do get it.  Look at the additional information I put in my answer.  That should get you going...

Answer (score 0):

OK, I was actually looking to create a block dynamically. This post here may be useful if anyone needs this in future : http://drupal.org/node/1709954

Comment: Yes, the suggestion above is for creating blocks dynamically.  Essentially, I was just saying you can copy the way block creation is done by the block module itself (by looking at the code in the function I suggested). You can, of course, insert that *anywhere* you want in your code and build a block totally on the fly... i.e. dynamically.  Anyway, I just wanted to clarify in case I didn't make that clear.  But I'm glad you found more than one way to do it!